# can not display widget through class def in existing frame

Tags: python, class, tkinter, widget, frame

looking through blogs, tutorials and such, I have not been able to understand why the following code will not display a Label in a Frame.  I can perform this task well when I do not define a class, but I want to create this application to be able to create Frames and other widgets more dynamically.  Here is the code.  **init** works fine and displays a Frame in the root window appropriately.  the code runs with out any errors.  I have added print statements and print(type()) statements through out the add_heading function, but still no label gets displayed.  Hopefully someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.  Thanks in advance

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from tkinter import *

class CompFrame(Tk):

    def __init__(self, parent, rows, columns, title):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.root = parent
        f_w = screen_width/3
        f_h = screen_height * .90
        self = LabelFrame(root, text=title, width=f_w, height=f_h, bg="light grey")
        self.grid_columnconfigure(columns, weight=1)
        self.grid(row=rows, column=columns)
        self.grid_propagate(False)

    def add_heading(self, title):
        label_width=12
        ftitle = Label(self, text=title)
        ftitle.configure(font='Helvetica 24 bold', width=label_width)
        ftitle.place(x=".5i", y=".2i")

root = Tk()
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d%d%d" % (screen_width,screen_height,0,0))

Calibrator = PhotoImage(file="image1.png")
Feeeder = PhotoImage(file="image2.PNG")

frame1 = CompFrame(root, 0, 0, "Component 1")
frame1.add_heading("NATURAL")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your `CompFrame` needs to inherit from `Frame`, not `Tk`.  That's not the whole problem, but it's part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `self = LabelFrame(root ...` part is guilty, maybe try something like this to keep control on the labelframe :

```
from tkinter import *

class CompFrame(Frame): # Edit with Bryan Oakley comment

    def __init__(self, parent, rows, columns, title):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.root = parent
        f_w = screen_width/3
        f_h = screen_height * .90
        self.labelframe = LabelFrame(root, text=title, width=f_w, height=f_h, bg="light grey")
        self.labelframe.grid_columnconfigure(columns, weight=1)
        self.labelframe.grid(row=rows, column=columns)
        self.labelframe.grid_propagate(False)

    def add_heading(self, title):
        label_width=12
        ftitle = Label(self.labelframe, text=title)
        ftitle.configure(font='Helvetica 24 bold', width=label_width)            
        ftitle.place(x=5, y=2)
```

Comment: Thank you - that works - I was spending days looking at this - Can you point me to a doc that explains this - I not only want this to work, but I want to understand why - I thought (wrongly) that when I created the LabelFrame in __init__ that since self was a LabelFrame the the instantiation of it would have carried through to the function.  I don't understand why it didn't.  Why would I have to create and attribute of self to hold the LabelFrame reference (I hope that makes sense)

Comment: in a class, `self` refers to the instance you've created `frame1 = CompFrame(...)` so if you assign this `self` to another widget, you kinda messing up the objects.  To manage others widgets, just link them to a new class attribute like here with `self.labelframe`, then you follow a simple hierarchy with parents (root > compFrame > labelFrame > label)